# Why does this loop not change the columns in th excel file

Tags: python, csv, file, connect-four

I'm trying to make a loop that saves the progress in a game of connect four when a round ends.The csv has to display the game board as follows. Each blank spot is represented by a
'0', an 'O' is represented by a '2' and an 'X' by a 1. Now while this loop is supposed to loop through and change both the rows and the columns in the csv file, i get everyting stacked in one column. Why is that?

```
        if turn == 'X':
            turn = "O"
           
        else:
            board_deepcopy = copy.deepcopy(my_board)
            ans = input('Type s to save your progress : ')
            if ans == 's':
             nop = input('Type in the name of your save file :')
             f = open(nop + '.csv', 'a', newline = '')
             writer = csv.writer(f)
             
             for y in range(board_col):
                list1 = []
                for l in range(board_col):
                 if my_board[y][l] == 'X':
                   board_deepcopy[y][l] = '1'
                   list1.append(board_deepcopy[y][l])
                   writer.writerow(list1[l])
                   
                 elif my_board[y][l] == 'O':
                  
                   
                   board_deepcopy[y][l] = '2'
                   list1.append(board_deepcopy[y][l])
                   writer.writerow(list1[l])
                  
                 else:
                  
                   board_deepcopy[y][l] = '0'
                   list1.append(board_deepcopy[y][l])
                   writer.writerow(list1[l])
           
             f.close()
            
            turn = 'X'
```

(example of display of
board of 8 columns and 8 rows with an 'X' on column 1 and an 'O' on column 2:)
windows terminal:

```
      1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
    ________________________________________
   A|' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '|
   B|' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '|
   C|' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '|
   D|' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '|
   E|' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '|
   F|' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '|
   G|' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '|
   H| X    O   ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '|
    ---------------------------------------
```

csv display:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H 
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
5  0
6  0
7  0
8  1
... 
16 2 
17 0
18 0
19 0
... 
64 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is not doing what you want it to. You are appending to your list, but then you *directly* save the newly appended element to your `csv file`. What you want to do is to save the entire list after your `inner for loop` is done to your file and then go on with the `outer for loop`. Here is how I think you want to design your loop:

```
import csv

board_col = 4
my_board = [['X', '0', '0', '0'], 
            ['0', 'X', '0', '0'], 
            ['0', '0', 'X', '0'], 
            ['0', '0', '0', 'X']]

f = open('try.csv', 'a', newline = '')
writer = csv.writer(f)

for y in range(board_col):
    list1 = []
    for l in range(board_col):
        if my_board[y][l] == 'X':
            list1.append('1')
        elif my_board[y][l] == 'O':
            list1.append('2')
        else:
            list1.append('0')
    writer.writerow(list1)

f.close()
```